# rpy2: How to make ListVector with more than 1 elements?

Tags: python, list, rpy2

I'm using the rpy2 package in python to create a list within a list and then pass it back through R.

I am able to successfully get it to produce a list with 1 element but now I want it to produce a list with more than 1 element, such that when I call my list object in python it says: `ListVector with 2 elements.`

Here is the code I am working off:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

JobIDs = [2201795, 2201783]
r_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
nested_r_lists = []  # Initialize an empty list outside the loop
counter = 0
for i in JobIDs:
    print(i)
    # Create a new ListVector for each job id
    list_vector = ro.ListVector({'Excel_List' + str(i): r_list})
    # Append the ListVector to nested_r_lists
    nested_r_lists.extend([list_vector])

# Now nested_r_lists contains two elements, one for each job id
nested_r_lists
```

Inside: `nested_r_lists` is says this:

```
[<rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector object at 0x000001DE120810D0> [19]
 R classes: ('list',)
 [ListSexpVector]
   Excel_List2201795: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
   <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x000001DE11A26650> [19],
 <rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector object at 0x000001DE121D1410> [19]
 R classes: ('list',)
 [ListSexpVector]
   Excel_List2201783: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
   <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x000001DE12128750> [19]]
```

But when I call `nested_r_lists[0]` and `nested_r_lists[1]` it reports

```
ListVector with 1 elements.
Excel_List2201795   [19]
```

```
ListVector with 1 elements.
Excel_List2201783   [19]
```

Instead, I would like to call `nested_r_lists` and have the output be:

```
ListVector with 2 elements.
Excel_List2201795   [19]
Excel_List2201783   [19]
```

Please help! Thank you!